# Is the language $\{f(x)\mid \mbox{$x$ is the code of a machine accepting $f(x)$}\}$ recursively enumerable and undecidable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, proof-techniques, undecidability, encoding-scheme

This is text of an exercise I am working on:

Given a binary encoding scheme for the set of the  deterministic Turing machines with alphabet $\{0,1\}$ and a bijective and computable function $f: \{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$, prove that the language 
$$L=\{f(x)\mid \mbox{$x$ is an encoding of a machine that accepts $f(x)$}\}$$ is recursively enumerable and undecidable.

I don't know how to prove it, and I don't know where to start.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. Just copy-pasting an exercise from a textbook is not a suitable question for this site.

Comment: @D.W. The OP said s/he had no idea where to start. Seems like a pretty good answer to "What did you try?" (Yes, I know this is a minority position on my part.)

Comment: @RickDecker "I tried looking at the definitions and theorems X, Y and Z but I couldn't see how to use any of that" seems like a much better answer than something that's indistinguishable from "I didn't try."

Comment: @RickDecker Also, the answer then should be, "If your course was designed at least reasonably well, you *should* know where to start. Review the material!"

Answer (score 1):

Let $L_f = \{f(x)\mid x \text{ is the encoding of a TM }X\land X\text{ accepts }f(x)\}$

We'll make use of a

**Lemma**. If $f:\{0, 1\}^*\rightarrow \{0, 1\}^*$ is a computable bijection, then so is $f^{-1}$.

*Proof hint*. Obviously, $f^{-1}$ is a bijection, since $f$ is. Then use dovetailing to construct a TM that for any input string $y$ returns the (unique) $x$ for which $f(x)=y$.

---

**I. $L_f$ is r.e.**.

Construct a recognizer $R$ that will accept all and only strings $y\in L_f$ as follows

```
R(y) =
   compute x such that f(x) = y     // using the Lemma above
   if x is the encoding of a TM, X  // obviously possible to check
      simulate X on input y         // obviously can do this, too
      if X accepts y
         return accept
```

**II. $L_f$ is undecidible**.

Suppose, to the contrary, that there was a decider $D_f$ for $L_f$. Define another (decider) TM, $E_f$, to do the "opposite" of $D_f$, i.e., $E_f$ accepts a string if $D_f$ rejects and $E_f$ rejects a string if $D_f$ accepts it. Then let $z=f(\langle E_f\rangle)$.

If $z\in L_f$, then $E_f$ accepts $z$ by the definition of $L_f$ and so by the definition of $E_f$, $D_f$ rejects $z$ and so $z\notin L_f$, a contradiction. Similarly, we can show that, $z\notin L_f\Rightarrow z\in L_f$, another contradiction, so $L_f$ must be undecidable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment (now deleted?). Actually I have been wondering
whether the fact that *composing a computable bijection with a Gödel
enumeration gives a new Gödel enumeration* is a standard theorem known
to student. It seems so basic that it should be, but I do not know.

Comment: @babou. The Powers that Be deleted my comment. I agree that this "composition theorem" does seem basic. I can't, of course, speak for all students, but I can say that it comes as a surprise (at first) to many of mine.

Answer (score 0):

**Using formal notations rather than words would make your life easier.** Since you have a
binary encoding of  Turing Machines (TM), you should use a formal
notation for it.

For example you can give it a name, say $g$. Then an encoding $x$ of a
TM $M$ can be written $x=g(M)$, or if you want to use the common angle
bracket notation: $x=\langle_g M\rangle_g$. Note that I keep $g$ as a
subscript of the angle brackets, so that I can distinguish different
binary encodings of Turing Machines.

Now, if $g$ is a binary encoding scheme for TMs, then its composition
$h=f\circ g$ with a bijective and computable function $f$ (from binary
numbers to binary numbers) is also a binary encoding scheme for TMs,
such that (using the various possible notations) $h(M)=f(g(M))=\langle_h M\rangle_h=f(\langle_g M\rangle_g)$.

Now you can rewrite the definition of $L$ using this new binary
encoding scheme:
.$$\begin{align}
L&=\{f(x)\mid \mbox{$x$ is an encoding of a machine that accepts $f(x)$}\}\\
&=\{f(x)\mid \mbox{$x=\langle_g M\rangle_g$ and $M$ accepts $f(\langle_g M\rangle_g)$}\} \\
&=\{f(\langle_g M\rangle_g)\mid \mbox{$M$ accepts $f(\langle_g M\rangle_g)$}\}\\
&=\{\langle_h M\rangle_h\mid \mbox{$M$ accepts $\langle_h M\rangle_h$}\}
\end{align}$$

It is now easy to see that **L is recursively enumerable**, since for any
value $x$, we can test whether it is in $L$ by running the machine $M$
such that $x=\langle_h M\rangle_h$ with input $x$, which does
terminate when $x\in L$.

However, **$L$ is not decidable**. The proof goes by contradiction.
We first suppose that $L$ is decidable. Thus its complement $\overline
L$ is also decidable, and is recognized by a Turing machine $\overline
M$

If $\overline M$ accepts $\langle_h \overline M\rangle_h$, then
$\langle_h \overline M\rangle_h$ is in $\overline L$, the language
that $\overline M$ recognizes by definition. But this implies, by definition of
$\overline L$ that $\overline M$ does not accept $\langle_h \overline
M\rangle_h$.

But if $\overline M$ does not accept $\langle_h \overline M\rangle_h$,
then $\langle_h\overline M\rangle_h\notin L$ by definition of $L$. Thus $\langle_h\overline
M\rangle_h\in\overline L$. Hence since $\overline M$ recognizes
$\overline L$,  $\overline M$ must accept $\langle_h \overline
M\rangle_h$.

In both cases we have a contradiction. So the hypothesis that $L$ is
decidable cannot hold.